# How can I uninstall packages from the command line on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, command-line, package-management

I am wondering how one would uninstall software from the command line/terminal. What commands would I use?

Comment: What distro are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu. But I think it would be the same across all, at least all the Debian-based systems, correct?

Comment: This is a distribution specific question.  While someone could attempt to give an answer covering all the common package managers, I think it is better to refine your question as, "How can I uninstall software *on Ubuntu* using the command-line?" (or *on Fedora*, or whatever).

Comment: @TJonS - yes all the Debian based distros use `apt` and `dpkg` toos to my knowledge.

Comment: Packagekit should be in couple of years (I hope) the one-fits-all tool to manage packages.

Answer (score 11):

Depending on your distro:

1. Using Fedora/CentOS/RHEL

   ```
   $ yum remove <package name>
   -or-
   $ rpm -e <package name>
   ```
2. Debian/Ubuntu/Mint/...

   ```
   $ apt-get --purge remove <package>
   -or-
   $ aptitude purge <package>
   -or-
   $ dpkg -r <package>
   ```
3. SuSE

   ```
   $ rpm -e <package>
   -or-
   $ zypper remove <package>
   -or-
   $ zypper rm <package>
   ```
4. BSDs

   ```
   $ pkg_delete <package>
   ```
5. Gentoo

   ```
   - uninstall a package, but only if it isn't required anymore by others -
   $ emerge -c <package>
   - uninstall a package, no matter whether it is still required by others -
   $ emerge -C <package>
   ```
6. ArchLinux

   ```
   $ pacman -Rc <package>
   ```
7. [NixOS](http://nixos.org/nixos/manual/#idp697632)

   ```
   $ nix-env -e <package>
   ```

#### References

- [zypper cheatsheet](https://en.opensuse.org/images/1/17/Zypper-cheat-sheet-1.pdf)
- [Debian: How to Install or Remove DEB Packages Using dpkg](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/install-remove-deb-package/)
- [Chapter 5. Installing Applications: Packages and Ports](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/packages-using.html)
- [Pacman Rosetta](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman_Rosetta)

Comment: I guess I can change the title back now, lol. +1

Comment: @goldilocks - yeah I saw your original feedback, but figured it was easier to just list all the ways vs. asking the OP 8-).

Comment: @tjons - if this solved your issue you can mark it as accepted so other's know your issue's been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The archlinux project has a [nice comparison](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman_Rosetta) about common tasks for different package managers.

For debian/ubuntu you can use `apt-get`, `aptitude`, `dpkg`, `dselect`, `orphaner`, `debfoster`, and probably a few more. All of them can remove packages. Read the corresponding man pages to find out how to use them and which one to use in which situation.